# Which Webcam software provides live "fire effects"?

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, webcam, effects

I am looking for a webcam app that creates Live Effects. Cheese has 9 effects but it does not have the *Fire Effect* I am looking for. An effect I saw several years ago with a Flash web app. By *fire effect* I mean the effect in the screenshot attached below:

[image]

Comment: So you want a web-app that uses flash to do live webcam visual effects?

Comment: No wait what?. I want an app that does what I saw from this web app. A fire effect. Updated question to be more understandable and correct the thing I said about Cheese having the fire effect.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot for further and better explanation? Do you mean something like [this](http://gskinner.com/blog/assets/webcamFire2.jpg)?

Comment: Exactly that one. I was actually looking for it. At least an effect similar to that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.ws4gl.org/